# Backbone.js event handlers with certain names cause errors with nested views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following nested Backbone views for an HTML form and submit button:

```
var Button = Backbone.View.extend({
    enable: function() {
        this.$el.prop('disabled', false);
        return this;
    },
    disable: function() {
        this.$el.prop('disabled', true);
    }
};

var Form = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#login-form',
    events: {
        'submit': 'submit'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.submitBtn = new Button({el: this.$el.find(':submit')});
    }
    submit: function(e) {
        this.submitBtn.disable();
        // Do AJAX request and re-enable submit upon completion
        // ...
        return e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

The problem is, when I click the submit button, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'n.apply(t,r.concat(o.call(arguments)))')
```

And the Form instance's submit function never gets called.

Comment: What is different between your code and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/H6ejA/1/ ?

Comment: @muistooshort I've moved a portion of my code into the JSFiddle and can't find any difference that reproduces the error, but I'll keep trying. As I've said below, I've found a work-around, so I'm not under a huge amount of pressure to figure out *why* it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against my desk a bit, I've managed to fix the problem by renaming the handler function:

```
var Form = Backbone.View.extend({
    // ...
    events: {
        'submit': 'submitHandler'
    },
    // ...
    submitHandler: function(e) { /* ... */ }
};
```

There are two curious things, however. (1) If I remove the nested Button view, a handler named `submit` works as expected, and (2) with the Button view in place, renaming the Form view's submit event handler to something other than `submit` will work.

So what's going on? Is there something magic about calling the handler function `submit`?